# Itext5, highlight one word in a phrase

Tags: itext

I am designing my pdf with a table, so pdf cells recieve a phrase and not a paragraph.

I have this phrase:

```
Phrase subject = new Phrase( "Subject: " + NEWLINE + investigation.Title);
```

and I want the word "subject" will be highlighted with a diffrent font, how do I change the font for a single word in a phrase

I would like to do it somehing like that:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Conclusions", titleFont);
Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph(chunk), 1);
chapter.NumberDepth = (0);
chapter.Add(new Paragraph(investigation.InvestigationResult, textFont));
doc.Add(chapter);
```

but in a phrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your text and create a chunk for each part (or at least a chunk for the part that varies). You can set the font for each chunk individually and then add all chunks to a phrase.